# Change paper format for scrbook class (using package typearea)

Tags: koma-script, paper-size, typearea

I try to use scrbook class, and play with basic options - **paper size**. I know that is based on KOMA script and for these reasons I should use package `typearea` instead package geometry. See MNWE:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[paper=b4paper]{typearea}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
  \lipsum[2-8]
\end{document}
```

I got Latex error: Option clash for package typearea! So I try this

```
\documentclass[paper=b4paper]{scrbook}
%\usepackage[paper=b4paper]{typearea}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
  \lipsum[2-8]
\end{document}
```

This leads to Latex warning: Unused global option(s): [paper=b4paper]

Comment: `\documentclass[b4paper]{scrbook}` instead of `\documentclass[paper=b4paper]{scrbook}`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've found that KOMA classes don't change the page size if you don't pass the option `pagesize`.

So the solution should be:

```
\documentclass[b4paper,pagesize]{scrbook}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
  \lipsum[2-8]
\end{document}
```

I suppose that you get that warning because the b4 paper size is not defined in `typearea.sty`.

Comment: Thanks. `\documentclass[b4paper]{scrbook} \usepackage{lipsum} \begin{document} \lipsum[2-8] \end{document}` But this minimal code leads to `package typearea Warning: Bad type area settings!`

Comment: You need the complete warning: `Package typearea Warning: Bad type area settings!
(typearea)                The detected line width is about 27%
(typearea)                larger than the heuristically detected line width.
(typearea)                You should e.g. decrease DIV, increase fontsize
(typearea)                or change papersize.` Maybe you want to work with `￼\areaset`

Comment: Or use: `\documentclass[b4paper]{scrbook}
\typearea{calc}`

Comment: Should I therefore prefer to use the package geometry instead it?

Answer (score 0):

According to KOMA-Script manual *scrguien.pdf*, **Section 2.6 - Options and Macros to Influence the Page Layout** there is no need to load package `typearea` with a KOMA-Sript class, since it's including in scrbook, etc.

Also, the syntax of the option for the class wouldn't be `paper=b4paper` but just `b4paper`

So the manual would indicate:

```
\documentclass[b4paper]{scrbook}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
  \lipsum[2-8]
\end{document}
```